# Are there any ways to check whether a key exists with RedisTemplate?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

Are there any ways to check whether a key exists with RedisTemplate?
or in other words, are there any equivalent of Redis `exists` command in RedisTemplate API?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can use `public Boolean hasKey(K key)`.

You can just search exists in [redisTemplate javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#hasKey-K-)

Comment: how about `get(key) == null`?

Comment: @LeiYang, can't find `get(key)` api.